# Flutter. Why are there no libraries (pods) in iOS target (extension)? #142136

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, target

**Problem with flutter when trying to use target**

Steps to reproduce

1. I am adding a new target - AutoFill Credential Provider:
   [image]
2. I do everything as written here - https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/ios/app-extensions
3. In the settings "passwords" in the simulator choose my application:
   [image]
4. On some site I try to enter a password and click on "passwords":
   [image]

**Expected results**
I expect that when I open the app through the "passwords" then I will see my app fully working, but only through extension. For example a simple screen with login:

[image]

**Actual results**
But I get it wrong. I use Firebase, and so I understand that this extension (target) does not see my packages that I added to pubspec.yaml, or does not see pods pods:
[image]